# How to use where condition multiple times within one single sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my `table1` there is date like:

```
id      value
1       500
2       400
3       300
4       200
5       100
```

I want to set the data above within the show table:

```
d1      d2      d3      d4      d5
500     400     300     200     100
```

I am using the following sql query.

```
"SELECT `value` as d1 from `table1` WHERE `id`=1"
"SELECT `value` as d2 from `table1` WHERE `id`=2"
"SELECT `value` as d3 from `table1` WHERE `id`=3"
"SELECT `value` as d4 from `table1` WHERE `id`=4"
"SELECT `value` as d5 from `table1` WHERE `id`=5"
```

How will I make all the queries within single sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use aggregation:

```
select max(case when id = 1 then value end) as d1,
       max(case when id = 2 then value end) as d2,
       max(case when id = 3 then value end) as d3,
       max(case when id = 4 then value end) as d4,
       max(case when id = 5 then value end) as d5
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can work with separate rows, just filter the values:

```
select id, 
    value 
from t
where id in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

If you need all the values in a single row, use where to filter all the rows and conditional aggregation to pivot the data:

```
select max(case when id = 1 then value end) as d1,
       max(case when id = 2 then value end) as d2,
       max(case when id = 3 then value end) as d3,
       max(case when id = 4 then value end) as d4,
       max(case when id = 5 then value end) as d5
from t
where id in (1,2,3,4,5);
```